# Capistrano deploy error DigitalOcean Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm-capistrano, capistrano3, digital-ocean

I am following this tutorial to deploy my RoR 4 application on VPS (DigitalOcean) with nginx, Passenger and capistrano:

http://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/12.04

But when I run 'cap production deploy', I get the following error:

```
..
..
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Execute rvm:hook
DEBUG [971a1192] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rvm ] on 188.226.143.213
DEBUG [971a1192] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
cap aborted!
deploy
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:215:in `start'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:25:in `create_or_reuse_connection'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:173:in `ssh'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:126:in `block in _execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `tap'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `_execute'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:62:in `test'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook
```

I've been trying to fix the error for a few hours now, no luck.
Can't seem to find anything similar online either.

Any help would be appreciated,

Ulugbek

Comment: Fixed the problem. In case anyone encounters it, it's a SSH authentication problem. You have to add your own SSH key to authorized_keys file in .ssh folder. You can reuse the one generated for git

Comment: Hi, where did you add the key?

Comment: You need to create the folder yourself and write your public key to it. See http://webtonio.com/339/  for an example. Hope it helps.